# (La)TeX renderer for simple equations without overhead

Tags: windows, gratis, offline

I am a C# programmer. Whenever I want to try just a simple statement, using an IDE is too much overhead. Thus, I use LinqPad, where I can simply enter a single line of code which then executes. LinqPad eliminates all the overhead of needing a namespace, a class, a static function etc.

[image: LinqPad]

Now I'm looking for something similar, just for LaTeX equations. I want to be able to write

```
$\sum_{i=1}^n$
```

without all the overhead of

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\maketitle    
\end{document}
```

Basically similar to some SE sites like [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com) which allow formulas.

The program needs to be able to save the result as a graphics (PNG file preferred) and copy to clipboard.

I want it

- for Windows
- gratis
- for commercial use
- support for text mode(`$\sum_{i=1}^n$`) and math mode (`\[\sum_{i=1}^n\]`)

I found:

- [TeX equation editor](http://atomurl.net/math/), which is great. Unfortunately, it's browser based <strike>and for getting the result as an image, I need to take a screenshot.</strike>
- [Visual Math Editor](http://visualmatheditor.equatheque.net/index.html), which is available for download, but does not work in any of my browsers when opening from local file system.

Comment: Using TeX Equation Editor, why can you not just right-click on the generated image and Save Image/Picture As...? Most browsers support this - certainly Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and IE do.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: the result of the TeX equation editor is not an image. It looks like HTML. I can select single characters of it

Comment: I don't understand. I entered the two examples in your question body (`$\sum_{i=1}^n$` and `\[\sum_{i=1}^n\]`) into the TeX equation editor, and the only output it generated were images. Even when the selector was on "HTML (Fast)" instead of "Image" for the real-time renderer, the final (not real-time) output at the bottom was an image regardless.

Comment: @JohnY: ok, I didn't notice I can set it to "image". How do I make this work offline, so it does not download the image from chart.apis.google.com?

Comment: (1) I think you are still not reading what I am saying. There is both a real-time renderer (shows you stuff *as you are typing*) and another renderer which doesn't update until you click the "Add to user equation" button. That latter renderer **only** produces image output, so you **always** have image output **no matter what**.

Comment: (2) I don't know of a way to use that one off-line.